# Error al cargar un txt de archivos a dataGridView

Tags: c#, poo

Lo que pasa es que estoy trabajando en un proyecto de un hotel donde tengo que cargar una la lista  de un archivo de texto,y la verdad llevo muchos dias tratando de solucionarlo pero no he podido, cuando inicio el programa me sale me sale que el indice esta fuera de los limites de la matriz
"Excepcion no controlada por la aplicacion.Si hace click en Conitnuar, la aplicacion omitira este error e intentara continuar. Indice fuera de  los limites de la matriz"
 Este es el codigo:

```
{
    string linea;
    string[] destino_split;
    Ejecutiva ejecutivas;
    Sencilla sencillas;
    Suite suites;
    MiniBar miniBarEjecutiva;
    MiniBar miniBarSuite;
    List<Ejecutiva> listaejecutivas = new List<Ejecutiva>();
    List<Sencilla> listasencillas = new List<Sencilla>();
    List<Suite> listasuites = new List<Suite>();
    List<MiniBar> MinibarEjecutiva = new List<MiniBar>();
    List<MiniBar> MinibarSuite = new List<MiniBar>();/

    public Habitaciones()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



            StreamReader archivo = new StreamReader("C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\semestre5\Poo\ArchivosHotel\MinibarEjecutiva.txt");
            linea = archivo.ReadLine();
            while (linea != null)
            {
                destino_split = linea.Split('|');
                miniBarEjecutiva = new MiniBar(destino_split[0], int.Parse(destino_split[1]), int.Parse(destino_split[2]), int.Parse(destino_split[3]));
                MinibarEjecutiva.Add(miniBarEjecutiva);
                linea = archivo.ReadLine();
            }

            StreamReader archivo1 = new StreamReader("C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\semestre5\Poo\ArchivosHotel\MinibarSuite.txt");
            linea = archivo1.ReadLine();
            while (linea != null)
            {
                destino_split = linea.Split('|');
                miniBarSuite = new MiniBar(destino_split[0], int.Parse(destino_split[1]), int.Parse(destino_split[2]), int.Parse(destino_split[3]));
                MinibarSuite.Add(miniBarSuite);
                linea = archivo.ReadLine();
            }
```

Me selecciona la parte de :

```
destino_split = linea.Split('|');
                miniBarEjecutiva = new MiniBar(destino_split[0], int.Parse(destino_split[1]), int.Parse(destino_split[2]), int.Parse(destino_split[3]));
```

y dice "Indice fuera de los limites de la matriz" Entonces no he podido cargar la lista de texto, nesecito solucionar el problema y cargar la lista de texto
Alguna idea de que pueda pasar? Por favor ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como indica el error, el problema que tienes es que el índice que intentas obtener del array `destino_split` no existe, es decir, si intentas obtener `destino_split[3]` pero en esa posición no hay datos, te salta el mensaje de error que estás obteniendo.

Deberías hacer comprobaciones antes de tratar directamente con los datos del array, ya que una simple linea mal en el archivo que estás leyendo puede hacer que todo tu programa no funcione.

Una de las soluciones que podrías aplicar es la siguiente:

```
while (linea != null)
{
    destino_split = linea.Split('|');
    if (destino_split.Length >= 4)
    {
        miniBarEjecutiva = new MiniBar(destino_split[0], int.Parse(destino_split[1]), int.Parse(destino_split[2]), int.Parse(destino_split[3]));
        MinibarEjecutiva.Add(miniBarEjecutiva);
    }
    linea = archivo.ReadLine();
}
```

De esta manera sólo va a añadir un nuevo `MiniBar` cuando el split tenga las posiciones 0 - 3 con datos.

Te recomiendo tambíen usar `try/catch` para poder capturar las excepciones y que no te salga del programa cada vez que te de un error.

También te recomiendo usar de diferente forma el `while` para recorrer el archivo que vas a leer, ya que de la forma que lo tienes, si una línea no tiene información te puede saltar sin cargar casi datos, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
StreamReader archivo = new StreamReader("C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\semestre5\Poo\ArchivosHotel\MinibarEjecutiva.txt");
while (!archivo.EndOfStream)
{
    linea = archivo.ReadLine();
    destino_split = linea.Split('|');
    if (destino_split.Length >= 4)
    {
        miniBarEjecutiva = new MiniBar(destino_split[0], int.Parse(destino_split[1]), int.Parse(destino_split[2]), int.Parse(destino_split[3]));
        MinibarEjecutiva.Add(miniBarEjecutiva);
    }
}
```

De ésta forma obligas al `while` a recorrer todo el archivo hasta el final.

Comment: Oye gracias, ya no sale el error pero pasa algo y es que parece que si lo carga el archivo de texto pero no aparecen los datos  en el dataGridView,no aparece nada. Sabes por que no los muestra?

Comment: @yehawpoo Cómo introduces los datos a la grid? No está puesto ese código en la pregunta.

Comment: dataGridView2.DataSource = miniBarEjecutiva;
Asi lo tengo, intente ponerlo por filas y columnas pero no da

Comment: @yehawpoo Y depurando el código te sale que `miniBarEjecutiva` tiene datos?

Comment: no, no dice nada, una vez de inicia esta vacio
actua como si no hubiese cargado, ni hecho algun cambio
que pena molestarte, pero no he podido solucionarlo :(

Comment: @yehawpoo Entonces tienes un problema en la lectura del archivo, no debe estar bien el formato del archivo o no debes estar cargandolo bien, asegurate de que el archivo tiene las lineas con campos delimitados con `|` y que se cargan correctamente los datos.

Comment: lo tengo delimitado con |
Mira asi lo tengo en el bloc de notas :
-licor|4|25000|100000
botellaAgua|2|3500|7000
kitAseo|1|9000|9000
gaseosa|2|3000|6000
 Todo vertical

Comment: @yehawpoo He editado la respuesta, comprueba eso que te he puesto nuevo

Comment: OYE MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS! ya me funciono, te lo agradezco mucho, no te puedo puntear por que soy nuevo :( pero muchas gracias. que pena la molestia,  te queria preguntar que si tal vez pueda preguntarte después otra cosa si me surge una duda con el programa?

Comment: @yehawpoo Puedes postular las preguntas que quieras en SOes. No olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta (el tick que te aparece)